# curl_exec and file_get_html

Tags: dom, cookies, curl

I am trying to collect cookies from a page to transmit it to another one and so I used the curl library. Yet I would like to parse the output page and for that I would need file-get-html as command find on the output from curl-exec returns an error. How do I fill the gap?

Comment: What language should this be in? *<Insert-obligatory-improve-accept-rate-comment-here>.*

Comment: Ok, I fixed it getting rid of curl and employing the context of the file-get-html function to inject the cookies into the url.